# Send mail with smtplib using proxy

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, proxy, smtplib

I have a very basic piece of Python code:

```
    import smtplib
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
    problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr,  message)
```

Is there solution to run it behind an HTTP proxy? I am using Python 3.4.1 on Linux with the `http_proxy` variable set.

Now I am getting a timeout from SMTP, but if I run this code from a proxy-free network, it works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there solution to run it behind an HTTP proxy?

No, HTTP is a different protocol than SMTP and the proxy is for HTTP only. If you are very lucky you might be able to create a tunnel using the `CONNECT` command to the outside SMTP server, but usually the ports used for CONNECT are restricted so that you will not be able to create a tunnel to an outside host port 25 (i.e. SMTP).